# React.js (Reference Error: React is not defined)

Tags: html, reactjs

I've attached copies of the code below.  Only two files in my project now, app.js and index.html.  When I go to google developers' tool and console, the log statement isn't going through.  When I type react or react-dom into console I am told Reference Error: React is not defined.  This is what a Udemy tutorial has told me to do last updated 5/19 so this should work.  I have tried putting import React from "react"; in the top of the files but that doesn't work either.  Any suggestions?

```
//app.js
console.log("App.js is running!)


//index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Indecision App</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.0.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.0.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
  <script src="/scripts/app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Does it work if you use any *current* version of react, i.e. React 16.x?

Comment: Are you typing them in lower case like 'react' and 'react-dom'? If so, try `React` and `ReactDOM` (no dash in between)

Comment: @Drew Reese.  Whoops, I edited it to RN 16.x which is what I meant to originally post! But nope, that does not solve the error!

Comment: @ultimoTG. I have tried both with uppercase, lowercase, with dash, and without dash, still have the same error!

Comment: Seems [CDN link](https://reactjs.org/docs/cdn-links.html) may also need to specify a `crossorigin` attribute on the scripts.

Comment: I am not sure how to accept your answer, but that solved the error!  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you'll need to also specify the `crossorigin` attribute on the scripts as per the react [CDN-links docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/cdn-links.html).

```
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```